# Android ALerDialog - unable to add windows exception

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

So basically I'm using a TabGroupActivity inside my TabHost,so I can switch different activities inside of one tab.Two days before the code that I'm running right now was ok,without any exceptions.But in that time I was flipping views inside the tab.Now I change all views with different activities.So my situation is something like that:

```
Main tab Activity -> opens Second activity -> which opens the third activity ,where the AlertDialog is.
```

The code I'm using is that :

```
Button deactivate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deactivate);
        deactivate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder( getParent() )
                .setTitle( "Warning" )
                .setMessage( "The collection will be removed completely from the device.You can reactivate it later again.This operation requires internet connection." )
                .setPositiveButton( "Go ahead", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d("AlertDialog", "Positive");
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton( "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d("AlertDialog","Negative");
                    }
                })
                .show();    

            }

    });
```

and the Exception is :

```
08-14 11:08:33.254: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4726): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 11:08:33.254: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4726): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@463430d0 is not valid; is your activity running?
08-14 11:08:33.254: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4726):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:509)
08-14 11:08:33.254: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4726):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
08-14 11:08:33.254: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4726):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
08-14 11:08:33.254: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4726):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
08-14 11:08:33.254: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4726):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
08-14 11:08:33.254: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4726):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
08-14 11:08:33.254: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4726):     at com.stampii.stampii.mystampii.MyCollectionId$4.onClick(MyCollectionId.java:74)
08-14 11:08:33.254: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4726):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-14 11:08:33.254: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4726):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)
08-14 11:08:33.254: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4726):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-14 11:08:33.254: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4726):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-14 11:08:33.254: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4726):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
08-14 11:08:33.254: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4726):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
08-14 11:08:33.254: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4726):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 11:08:33.254: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4726):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-14 11:08:33.254: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4726):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-14 11:08:33.254: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4726):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-14 11:08:33.254: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4726):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried with `this`, `MyCollecionId.this`, with adding Context ad etc.but I can't get the things to work.Any ideas how to solve that problem?

Comment: That's beacause your activity isn't running. Why are you using getParent() in the constructor?? Try with MyActivity.this (where the AlertDialog is), and check you don't "finish" your activity before showing the dialog

Comment: I have finish only in a setOnClickListener in a back button,nowhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Button deactivate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deactivate);
        deactivate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder( yourActivity.this )
                .setTitle( "Warning" )
                .setMessage( "The collection will be removed completely from the device.You can reactivate it later again.This operation requires internet connection." )
                .setPositiveButton( "Go ahead", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d("AlertDialog", "Positive");
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton( "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d("AlertDialog","Negative");
                    }
                })
                .show();    

            }

    });
```

try it out, pass your running activity's context

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Button deactivate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deactivate);
        deactivate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!isFinishing()){
                new AlertDialog.Builder( yourActivity.this )
                .setTitle( "Warning" )
                .setMessage( "The collection will be removed completely from the device.You can reactivate it later again.This operation requires internet connection." )
                .setPositiveButton( "Go ahead", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d("AlertDialog", "Positive");
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton( "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d("AlertDialog","Negative");
                    }
                })
                .show();    
               }
            }

    });
```

Comment: Actually I solved my problem with getParent() and made some changes in my TabGroupActivity class.I saw where was the problem.But thanks anyway.I know that this code is working too so I'll accept the answer.